# Edit Word Document in Angular at Runtime

Tags: angular

I want to display word (.docx) file content without changing format and want to update content at runtime.
How to achieve this using Angular ?

I tried displaying word (.docx) file content but it shows UTF-8 format and additionally want to edit those data but i don't have an idea to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use [WebViewer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@pdftron/webviewer), WebViewer supports more than simply viewing Office documents, offering annotation, mail merge on DOCX templates, text editing, page manipulation, redaction, form filling and creation, and much more.